# Advantage of ImageView over LinearLayout background

Tags: android-layout, android

Is there any advantage in using an ImageView over just setting the backgrounnd of a LinearLayout to an image?
For example, here is just setting the background image of a LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/container">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:orientation="vertical" > 
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is using an ImageView inside a LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/container">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bg" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Does it matter which one I use? I am currently using the LinearLayout background way and am wondering if there are advantages to doing it the other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See, the thing is that when you set a background to a layout. The image reshapes and resizes to the dimensions of that layout. So when you set an image as a background, it sometimes becomes too tall or too wide. And that's probably not what you're looking for.

However when you use an `ImageView`, you can set the width and height to 'match_parent' and then use a feature called `android:scaleType` in the layout xml and use the `centerCrop` option and it will automatically... you got it... center and crop the image. Now note that the actual `ImageView` does not get cropped. It just increases its size so that it can fill the bounds of the container layout.

For your purpose, I would recommend using a `RelativeLayout` and putting an `ImageView` and then a `TextView` on it. *Unless* your `LinearLayout` has the same dimension ratios as your image. Then you can set the image as a background.

Ultimately the decision is up to you. See what works out best for you...

Comment: The way I have it now, I set the width and height of the linearLayout in the xml by using custom attributes custom:width="100dp" and custom:height="100dp" and then this sets the LinearLayout width to 100dp and I set the background to the given image. So I think my image should always fit perfectly in the LinearLayout. Is that what you mean by "unless your linearlayout has the same dimenion ratios..."?

Comment: if you're saying that the width by height ratio of your `LinearLayout` (let's say 100 x 100 in your case) is the same as your width by height ratio of your image, then yes, that is exactly what i mean

Answer (score 2):

By setting the `imageView` in a `linearLayout`, you will not be able to put anything over the image view. It will put all of the widgets one after another, so you would not accomplish the "background image effect". However, if the root container was `relativeLayout`, you could. But I don't see the reason or the advantage to doing it this way. *Maybe* if you wanted to control the size of the image more extensively.

Ultimately, it is best practice to just set background of your container.

Comment: That is one of the reasons I am doing it that way, so I can have text on the image.

Comment: The don't add a `imageView` to a `linearLayout`. Just set the background to your root element.

Comment: It helped, but I would like to hear what others have to say. I'll choose an answer, don't worry